# PHP reading a txt data file and passing data to array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to extract the following data from a txt file(displayed in link),then save every field specified on mysql, my problem is how do I get every field  contained in a row since its separated by spaces

I tried,
   `array = explode(' ', $line);`  but that method saves spaces

I would like to pu it into an array ,

```
Array=(
 [0] => '1',
 [ 1] => 'OC1',
 [2] => 'Columna', 
 [3] => '1',
 [4] => 'IN45X104',
 [5] => '11745'
 ....
 );
```

[image]

Comment: http://codepad.org/fJqNaW3H
your code should work fine with `explode()`

Comment: if multiple spaces, use `preg_split('/\s+/')` http://codepad.org/3bnegwBC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace("/\s[\s]+/",",",$string);
$array = explode(",",$string);
```

`preg_replace` just work like `str_replace` but allow you to replace with using regular expression `/\s[\s]+/` matches multiple white spaces and then all that white spaces replace with single `","` so its easy to explode now.

Function Source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Code only or link only answers are not encouraged, you should add some explanatory text to your answer.

Comment: unset($array[count($array)-1]);

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$tok = strtok($string, " \n\t\x0B\0");
while ($tok !== false) 
{
 echo "Word=$tok<br />";
 $tok = strtok(" \n\t\x0B\0");
}
```

> strtok() splits a string (str) into smaller strings (tokens), with
>   each token being delimited by any character from token. That is, if
>   you have a string like "This is an example string" you could tokenize
>   this string into its individual words by using the space character as
>   the token.

Answer (score 0):

Use preg_split() to match complex delimiters

http://codepad.org/fhsTWsZc

```
<?php

$line="test test2  test3";
$array=preg_split('/\s+/',$line);
print_r($array);
```