# Extract data from text file and store it to array

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, text

i am looking for the way to extract data from text file and store it to array so that in later stages i can use the stored data in array pass to another view.

First , i have used pdfparser to convert pdf to text file and now  need to get data from that text file to pass to the another view.

I require expert advice on this, please help

here is the code

function do_parse($file_name)
    {

```
             $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
             $pdf    = $parser->parseFile(APPPATH.'/upload/'.$file_name); 

             $details  = $pdf->getDetails();
            // Retrieve all pages from the pdf file.
            $pages  = $pdf->getPages();

             // Loop over each page to extract text.
            foreach ($pages as $page) {
             echo $page->getText();
             foreach ($details as $property => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
              $value = implode(', ', $value);
              }
               echo $property . ' => ' . $value . "\n";
```

}
}

Comment: In what format are the informations saved in the textfile? Is it csv, just plain text or something different?

Comment: its a pdf form file that i have converted to text file, its neither in CSV nor PLAIN text..............................................L&T TECHNOLOGY SERVICES LIMITED Form 16 Digitally Signed Form16 Details : Employee Name : Rahul Saini Employee PAN : BSRJHDH Employee Serial

Comment: i need to extract Employee name and his PAN

Comment: is the file long/big?

Comment: Please add more code, and an example of how you saved the array in the txt file. Using JSON to store data is usually a better alternative

Comment: i am just taking the output in browser , i don't know whether it is long or big,, i have share only few lines of that text with you...

Comment: @Kitanga Nday i have pasted the parse code

Comment: what di you mean you are just taking the output from the browser. Don't you have access to the file?

Comment: @Kitanga Nday off-course i have access to this file , just i am not stroing it coz i dont need to store i just need the data from it

Comment: Have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870219/php-reading-a-txt-data-file-and-passing-data-to-array)